# How do you position a label in the center of screen in a scrollview within Kivy?

Tags: image, label, kivy, scrollview

I'm having difficulty in positioning a label that has an image added using canvas within a scrollview. The desirable output is to have a label with text content as a paragraph followed by a label with an image and then followed by another label with text content as a paragraph.

The image is displaying in the correct position vertically as in its between the two text labels, but it is not positioning center when I attempt to scale down the image by multiplying the self.parent.width by .9 or whatever the decimal.  It's binding it to the left screen and padding in the label is not working whereas it does work in the labels with text content.  I have searched for documentation and other examples but could not find a solution to this.  If anyone has experience with this or can provide any guidance, I'd greatly appreciate it.  Please see my code below:

```
BoxLayout:
    size_hint_y: .7
    orientation: 'vertical'
    canvas.before:
       Color:
           rgba: rgba('#FFFFFF')
       Rectangle:
           pos: self.pos
           size: self.size

    ScrollView:
        id: sv
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.parent.height
        effect_cls: 'ScrollEffect'
        GridLayout:
            id: Content
            cols: 1
            size: self.minimum_size
            size_hint: (1, None)
            height: labelscroll1.texture_size[1]
            Label:
                id: labelscroll1
                padding: ['20dp', '0dp']
                color: rgba('#000000')
                font_size: mtx.sp(14)
                text_size: self.width, None
                size: self.parent.width, self.texture_size[1]
                size_hint: (None,None)
                text: "Some text"

            Label:
                id: labelscroll2
                padding: ['5dp','0dp']
                size_hint: (None, None)
                width:  max(self.texture_size[0], self.parent.width)
                height: 300
                halign: 'center'
                markup: True
                canvas.before:
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size                                 
                        source: 'Table.png'

            Label:
                id: labelscroll3
                padding: ['20dp', '0dp']
                color: rgba('#000000')
                font_size: mtx.sp(14)
                text_size: self.width, None
                size: self.parent.width, self.texture_size[1]
                size_hint: (None,None)
                text: "Some text"
```

The indentations are four spaces in actual code but the formatting might be slightly off in here due to pasting.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your actual code, I can only guess at what the problem actually is. But a good way to get something centered within a `GridLayout` cell is to use the `AnchorLayout`. Try replacing your middle `Label` in your `kv` with:

```
        AnchorLayout:
            size_hint: (1.0, None)
            height: 300
            Label:
                id: labelscroll2
                padding: ['5dp','0dp']
                size_hint: (None, None)
                width:  max(self.texture_size[0], self.parent.width)
                height: 300
                halign: 'center'
                markup: True
                canvas.before:
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size                                 
                        source: 'Table.png'
```

Comment: John, I apologize for the delayed reply to your first post.  Thank you for contributing.  I tried your suggested solution and it worked perfectly!  Thank you very much!  Best regards, Andrew